# Learning to rank algorithm Tensorflow error Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tensorflow

I know that this kind of question was asked before and I've checked all the answers and I have tried several times to find a solution but they don't seems to work in my case. The problem is that I used a dataframe and convert these to a Dataset.Tensor. The error occurs by the line model= MovielensModel() and is the following: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

```
df_huurder=pd.read_csv('cat_huurder.csv', index_col=False)
df_succes = pd.read_csv('succesrate.csv', sep= ',', index_col=False)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(df_succes_x,df_succes_y, test_size=0.2,random_state=123)

X_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype=tf.int64)
X_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype=tf.int64)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.int64)
y_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test, dtype=tf.int64)

movie_titles = df_succes['id_comm'].tolist()
user_ids = df_succes['id_huurder'].tolist()

unique_movie_titles = list(set(movie_titles))
unique_user_ids = list(set(user_ids))
print(unique_movie_titles)

class RankingModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        embedding_dimension = 32

        # Compute embeddings for users.
        self.user_embeddings = tf.keras.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
          tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, embedding_dimension)
        ])

        # Compute embeddings for movies.
        self.movie_embeddings = tf.keras.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=unique_movie_titles, mask_token=None),
          tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, embedding_dimension)
        ])

        # Compute predictions.
        self.ratings = tf.keras.Sequential([
          # Learn multiple dense layers.
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
          # Make rating predictions in the final layer.
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        ])

    def call(self, inputs):

        user_id, movie_title = inputs

        user_embedding = self.user_embeddings(user_id)
        movie_embedding = self.movie_embeddings(movie_title)

        return self.ratings(tf.concat([user_embedding, movie_embedding], axis=1))

class MovielensModel(tfrs.models.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ranking_model: tf.keras.Model = RankingModel()
        self.task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
          loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()]
        )

    def call(self, features: Dict[str, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:
        return self.ranking_model(
            (features["user_id"], features["movie_title"]))

    def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
        labels = features.pop("user_rating")

        rating_predictions = self(features)

        # The task computes the loss and the metrics.
        return self.task(labels=labels, predictions=rating_predictions)

model= MovielensModel()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=-0.1))

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Comment: There is similar model available in `Tensorflow.org` website. Following this [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_ranking) will help you to solve your existing issue.